# How to wrap PyTorch functions and implement autograd?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, autograd

I'm working through the PyTorch tutorial on [Defining new autograd functions](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#pytorch-defining-new-autograd-functions). The autograd function I want to implement is a wrapper around [`torch.nn.functional.max_pool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.max_pool1d). Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.autograd as tag

class SquareAndMaxPool1d(tag.Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, kernel_size, stride=None, padding=0, dilation=1, \
                return_indices=False, ceil_mode=False):
        ctx.save_for_backward( input )

        inputC = input.clone() #copy input
        inputC *= inputC

        output = F.max_pool1d(inputC, kernel_size, stride=stride, \
                              padding=padding, dilation=dilation, \
                              return_indices=return_indices, \
                              ceil_mode=ceil_mode)

        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = get_max_pool1d_grad_somehow(grad_output)
        return 2.0*input*grad_input
```

My question is: how to I get the gradient of the wrapped function? I know that there are probably other ways to do this given how simple the example I present is, but what I want to do fits this framework and requires me to implement an `autograd` function.

Edit: After examining [this blog post](https://jhui.github.io/2018/02/09/PyTorch-Variables-functionals-and-Autograd/) I decided to try the following for `backward`:

```
def backward(ctx, grad_output):
    input, output = ctx.saved_tensors
    grad_input = output.backward(grad_output)
    return 2.0*input*grad_input
```

with `output` added to the saved variables. I then run the following code:

```
x = np.random.randn(1,1,5)
xT = torch.from_numpy(x)
xT.requires_grad=True
f = SquareAndMaxPool1d.apply
s = torch.sum(f(xT,2))
s.backward()
```

and I get `Bus error: 10`.

Say, `xT` is `tensor([[[ 1.69533562, -0.21779421,  2.28693953, -0.86688095, -1.01033497]]], dtype=torch.float64)`, then I would expect to find that `xT.grad` is  `tensor([[[ 3.39067124, -0.        ,  9.14775812, -0.        , -2.02066994]]], dtype=torch.float64)` after calling `s.backward()` (that is `2*x*grad_of_max_pool`, with `grad_of_max_pool` containing `tensor([[[1., 0., 2., 0., 1.]]], dtype=torch.float64)`).

I've figured out why I get a `Bus error: 10`. It appears that the above code leads to a recursive call of my `backward` at `grad_input = output.backward(grad_output)`. So I need to find some other way to get the gradient of `max_pool1d`. I know how to implement this in pure Python, but the result would be much slower than if I could wrap the library code.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the gradient"? Implement? Calculate?

Comment: @Jatentaki I mean that I believe that PyTorch has a way to calculate the gradient in question, given the right function call(s). I am having trouble figuring out what that call might be. I have just added an attempted solution to the question that fails. Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have picked a rather unlucky example. `torch.nn.functional.max_pool1d` is not an instance of `torch.autograd.Function`, because it's a PyTorch built-in, defined in C++ code and with an [autogenerated](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ac00e85e36c236f141d0621bfbbbbe8c9ffeefd1/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml#L1353) Python binding. I am not sure if it's possible to get the `backward` property via its interface.

Firstly, in case you haven't noticed, you don't need to write any custom code for backpropagation of this formula because both power operation and `max_pool1d` already have it defined, so their composition also is covered by the autograd. Assuming your goal is an exercise, I would suggest you do it more manually (without falling back to `backward` of `max_pool1d`). An example is below

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.autograd as tag

class SquareAndMaxPool1d(tag.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        # we're gonna need indices for backward. Currently SquareAnd...
        # never actually returns indices, I left it out for simplicity
        kwargs['return_indices'] = True

        input_sqr = input ** 2
        output, indices = F.max_pool1d(input_sqr, kernel_size, **kwargs)
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, indices)

        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, indices = ctx.saved_tensors

        # first we need to reconstruct the gradient of `max_pool1d`
        # by putting all the output gradient elements (corresponding to
        # input elements which made it through the max_pool1d) in their
        # respective places, the rest has gradient of 0. We do it by
        # scattering it against a tensor of 0s
        grad_output_unpooled = torch.zeros_like(input)
        grad_output_unpooled.scatter_(2, indices, grad_output)

        # then incorporate the gradient of the "square" part of your
        # operator
        grad_input = 2. * input * grad_output_unpooled

        # the docs for backward
        # https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function.backward
        # say that "it should return as many tensors, as there were inputs
        # to forward()". It fails to mention that if an argument was not a
        # tensor, it should return None (I remember reading this somewhere,
        # but can't find it anymore). Anyway, we need to
        # return a (grad_input, None) tuple to avoid a complaint that two
        # outputs were expected
        return grad_input, None
```

We can then use the [numerical gradient checker](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.autograd.gradcheck) to verify that the operation works as expected.

```
f = SquareAndMaxPool1d.apply
xT = torch.randn(1, 1, 6, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)
tag.gradcheck(lambda t: f(t, 2), xT)
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't address your question of how to get the `backward` of `max_pool1d`, but hopefully you find my answer useful enough.

Comment: Thanks! You are right that this is an exercise in how (or whether it's possible) to wrap a pytorch function and get autograd to work without knowing the details of the pytorch function. I think I'll take a different approach, where I put the parts that come before `max_pool1d`  into one autograd function and the stuff after in another, but I'm finding what you wrote useful and helpful in other ways. :)

Answer (score 5):

The problems you had with the recursive calls is actually coming from the `output` and the fact that by default the `with no_grad` is a default behavior it seems in class declaration inherited from `torch.autograd.Function`. If you check `output.grad_fn` in `forward`, it will probably be `None`, and in `backward`, it will probably link to the function object `<SquareAndMaxPool1d...>` thus causing the recursive calls. If you are still interested in how to do exactly what you asked, here is an example with `F.linear`:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

class custom_Linear(nn.Linear):
    def forward(self, _input):
        return Custom_Linear_AGfn_getAround.apply(_input, self.weight, self.bias)

class Custom_Linear_AGfn_getAround(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, _input, _weight, _bias):
        print('Custom forward')
        with torch.enable_grad():
            detached_input = _input.detach()
            detached_input.requires_grad_(True)
            detached_weight = _weight.detach()
            detached_weight.requires_grad_(True)
            detached_bias = _bias.detach()
            detached_bias.requires_grad_(True)
            _tmp = F.linear(detached_input, detached_weight, detached_bias)
        ctx.saved_input = detached_input
        ctx.saved_param = detached_weight, detached_bias
        ctx.save_for_backward(_tmp)
        _output = _tmp.detach()
        return _output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_out):
        print('Custom backward')
        _tmp, = ctx.saved_tensors
        _weight, _bias = ctx.saved_param
        detached_input = ctx.saved_input
        with torch.enable_grad():
            _tmp.backward(grad_out)
        return detached_input.grad, _weight.grad, _bias.grad
```

Basically, it is just about constructing a small isolated graph for the part of interest without messing up with the main graph, and using `grad_fn` and `requires_grad` to keep track of the graphs when looking at what to detach and what is needed for the isolated graph.

About the tricky parts:

- detaching the weight and bias: you could go without but EITHER you then pass `_weight` and `_bias` through the `save_for_backward` and will have `_weight.grad`, `_bias.grad` as `None` inside `backward` BUT once outside `_weight.grad`, `_bias.grad` will have their correct values, OR you pass them through an attribute as say `ctx.saved_param`, in which case, you will have to manually put `None` for the last two returned values of `backward` (return `detached_input.grad, None, None`), otherwise you will obtain twice the correct value when you check the weight and bias gradient outside of backward afterwards.
- as said at the beginning, `backward` and `forward` for inherited class of `torch.autograd.Function` seems to have a `with no_grad` behavior by default. Thus, removing `with torch.enable_grad():` in the above code will result in `_tmp.grad_fn` being `None` (Could not understand why by default `_tmp` had `grad_fn` to `None` and `requires_grad` to `False` in `forward` despite having required the gradient for `detached_input` until I bumped into: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7698)
- I believe but I did not check that you might get a double `grad_fn` for the `_output` if you do not detach it as when I do not have the `with torch.enable_grad()` and do not detach the output, resulting in `_tmp.grad_fn` being None in forward, it does acquire `<Custom_Linear_AGfn_getAround...>` `grad_fn` in the `backward` (and results in the infinite recursive calls).